# Mirror error: Could not spawn assetId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-mirror

I use Unity 2020.3.30f1 and Mirror 65.0.0.

In "Build Setting", I build and run server by checking "Server Build" then "Click and Run" button.
In Unity editor, I start on my Offline scene.

My client connect to the server and player prefab is spawned then i got following errors:

```
Spawn scene object not found for D9ADFFC4F5D145F8.
Make sure that client and server use exactly the same project.
This only happens if the hierarchy gets out of sync.
```

```
Could not spawn assetId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 scene=D9ADFFC4F5D145F8 netId=2
```

I search on internet and [Mirror doc](https://mirror-networking.gitbook.io/docs/), but I found nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I double checked on Mirror examples and script `SceneInterestManagement` script one missing on `NetworkManager` in OfflineScene.

I post that answer because I spent time to find it and it could help somebody.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Mirror adds more than 1 NetworkManager or adds NetworkIdentity in your NetworkManager gameObject
Just remove it and have only 1 NetworkManager in your scene.